# Bootstrap modal shadow displays on modal

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-modal

I have a bootstrap modal on my web page, but each time I open the modal, it opens below its shadows, how can I resolve this?

```
<div id="logoutModal" bsModal #myModal="bs-modal" class="modal" 
tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel" aria- 
hidden="true" >
    <div class="modal-dialog modal-lg modal-dialog-centered">
        <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-header">
                <h4 class="modal-title" id="myModalLabel">Sign Out</h4>
                <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" 
aria-hidden="true" aria-label="Close">×</button>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-body">
                <p><i class="fa fa-question-circle"></i> Are you sure you 
want to sign out? <br /></p>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-footer text-center">
                    <button class="btn btn-default btn-primary" data- 
dismiss="modal" (click)="confirmSignOut()">Sign out</button>
                    <button class="btn btn-default" data- 
dismiss="modal">Cancel</button>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

i have the solution now.
1. in my custom css file

```
.modal-backdrop {
  //hides the default modal shadow
  display: none;
}

.modal {
  //modal custom bachground/shadow
  background: rgba(0,0,0,0.5);
}

or

.modal{
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
}
.modal-backdrop{
  position: relative;
}
```

2. i write my modal html tag as follow.

```
 <div id="logoutModal" bsModal #myModal="bs-modal" class="modal" 
    tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel" aria- 
    hidden="true" data-backdrop="false" style="background: 
    rgba(0,0,0,0.5);">
    ....
</div>
```

and that solved my issue.

Answer (score 1):

This could happen when the modal is not a direct child of `<body>`.

Answer (score 0):

Excellent, This works for me...

Comment: Please use comment section to leave feeback to answers

Comment: Please don't add "thank you" as an answer. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation), you will be able to [vote up questions and answers](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/vote-up) that you found helpful. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/34377708)